# adding multiple rows in mysql table based on an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a form which allows people to message each other, a user can select multiple people to message, when i submit a form it gives me the name and id of people selected to message in an array. uptil here i am able to get it to work for a single recipient

I want to be able to use this array and INSERT message for each user in different rows of mysql table

this is the array that i get when i submit a form

```
Array (
[to_user_id] => Array
    (
        [0] => 54
        [1] => 55
    )

[subject] => aaa
[message] => bbb
[send_message] =>
```

this is the part of code that works for a single recipient but not multiple

```
$to_user_id_array = ($_POST['to_user_id']);
$params = array(
            ':to_user_id' => $to_user_id_array,
            ':subject' => $_POST['subject'],
            ':message' => $_POST['message'],
            ':sender_id' => $this->user_id,
            ':status' => "0",
            ':type' => "message",
            ':sender_name' => $sender_name,
            ':to_user_name' => $to_user_name,
            ':delete_received' => 'no',
            ':delete_sent' => 'no',

        );


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`sender_id`,`subject`,`comment`,`to_user_id`,`status`,`type`,`sender_name`,`to_user_name`,`delete_received`,`delete_sent`)
                                VALUES (:sender_id, :subject, :message, :to_user_id, :status, :type, :sender_name,:to_user_name,:delete_received,:delete_sent);";
        parent::query($sql, $params);
        $this->error = "<div class='alert alert-success'>" . _('Your message has been sent.') . "</div>";
```

Will really appreciate any help..

Comment: `for` or `foreach` loop on `to_user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me, i hope this helps someone else in similar position

```
while ($value = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $params = array(
        ':to_user_id' => $value['user_id'],
        ':subject' => $_POST['subject'],
        ':message' => $_POST['message'],
        ':sender_id' => $this->user_id,
        ':status' => "0",
        ':type' => "message",
        ':sender_name' => $sender_name,
        ':to_user_name' => $value['name'],
        ':delete_received' => 'no',
        ':delete_sent' => 'no',
    );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`sender_id`,`subject`,`comment`,`to_user_id`,`status`,`type`,`sender_name`,`to_user_name`,`delete_received`,`delete_sent`)
               VALUES (:sender_id, :subject, :message, :to_user_id, :status, :type, :sender_name,:to_user_name,:delete_received,:delete_sent);";

    parent::query($sql, $params);
}
```